# Help identifying this frame

Tags: vintage

This frame used to be black with a campagnolo sticker though under it I found a green layer of paint. When I went to set it up they told me it's probably an old UK or Belgium bike. For what i can see the frame number looks like 81    6836. 
Photos here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10JKLCWnSE7nxlYehOYcJJPFo_1fQvr6S

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A picture of the whole bike would be helpful, but the details you showed suggest an inexpensive bike, probably a basic hi-ten steel frame.

Comment: Can you also post a photo of the front of the bike? The decal on the head tube is usually very helpful

Comment: @Andrew The decal on the front is a newly placed sticker. I've been told the material is chromoly (said so cause of the weight of the frame), that's why I got curious in the first place. I will try to get a picture as soon as possible.

Comment: The pump peg is fairly unusual.  Everything else is pretty generic for a 60s-70s frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the wheels, chainring, cranks, chain, singlespeed thing, and single front brake are all non-original.   I'd even suspect the headset has been replaced - it looks far too new.

I'm going to guess its a Raleigh or otherwise English frame from the 80s.  Here's my old 1981 Raleigh Arena, and while the lug cuts are different, the seat stay caps look very similar.
[image: Own bike]

Also, one of the main similarities is the rear brake bridge, which is a plate of metal welded to the seat stays where a nicer bike would have a more-elegant brake bridge.

[image: Own work]

So no its not exactly this bike, but its this era and down at the lower end of the price range.

I'd be surprised if its chromolly steel - that always feels surprisingly light for a steel bike.